# How to analysis the memory usage of .apk mmap of Android application

Tags: android, memory-management, apk

I'm trying to analysis the memory usage of my Android application, however I found that my application always consumes huge memory resources in the .apk mmap section. Even though in the startup.

```
adb shell dumpsys com.testapp.foo

Applications Memory Usage (in Kilobytes):
Uptime: 3367859 Realtime: 3367859

** MEMINFO in pid 5286 [com.testapp.foo] **
                   Pss  Private  Private     Swap      Rss     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty    Total     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap     5256     5160        0        0     8436    13524     7183     2379
  Dalvik Heap     8282     7996        0        0    16504    16771     8386     8385
 Dalvik Other     7534     7480        0        0     9992
        Stack     1356     1356        0        0     1368
       Ashmem       17        0        0        0      536
    Other dev       16        0       16        0      304
     .so mmap      917      168        0        0    23464
    .jar mmap     1207        0        0        0    27964
    .apk mmap    64405      640    63400        0    65424
    .dex mmap       28        8        0        0      616
    .oat mmap      524        0        0        0    11940
    .art mmap     1300      644        0        0    19652
   Other mmap      195       40       96        0     1648
      Unknown      549      532        0        0     1376
        TOTAL    91586    24024    63512        0   189224    30295    15569    10764
```

Looks like my foo application took over 60MB in the .apk mmap, and I tried to analyze the usage via `adb shell cat /proc/<pid>/smaps`, but I still don't quite understand what was happened here, since the smaps doesn't profile the details of the memory consumption.

What's the possible solution here for me to profile the .apk mmap usage or what should I do here to reduce the mmap consumption?

Comment: "mmap" means memory mapping. In my understanding this should be the memory part where the APK file of your app is mapped into the RAM address space of your app. This means it looks like the APK would have been loaded to RAM but actually it is only mapped to some RAM addresses. Thus this section does not consume real RAM as all read requests are redirected to the APK in the filesystem.

Comment: For analyzing memory usage you should better use the Android Studio integrated Memory Profiler https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler